# Can I use Corinne Landcover high res forest data and WorldClim 30 arc Secs for species distribution model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, gis, qgis, terra

I am trying to create a species distribution model in R to predict where 8 species of mushrooms will grow dependent on the current weather. I have collected my dataset, so it contains the lat, lon, tavg(temperature average), prec(precipitation)(from World Clim). From Corinne land cover, I have high res forest data, water, and grassland.
The problem is now when I am trying to create the Raster Stack for the predictions, I changed the extent and then realised the resolutions are different so I cant merge the rasters.

```
> ext(forest_cropped_10min)
SpatExtent : -13.999962276492, 4.00158019814024, 48.9996486983881, 61.3000449251267 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Currently I'm trying to resample (terra) the forest data to match the climate data but its been working for an hour with only a 1/4 of the way completed.

```
#use variables to set the extent
ext <-ext(-14,4,49,61.3)
tempavg_cell_size <- cellSize(tempavg)

resampled_forest <- resample(all_forest, tempavg_cell_size, method = "bilinear")
```

I knew that this was potentially going to be an issue but the mushrooms I choose have preference of deciduous or coniferous trees so the general landcover data in geodata only refers to trees.

Additionally I tried the normal landcover data from Corinne but the crs was different and reprojection wasn't working for me using both R and QGIS.

This is my degree project and I'm just lost as to where to go now, I'm not a data analysis and only a soon to be software graduate.

Just need to know am I completely wasting my time? Any help appreciated

Comment: Hi featherAndLemons. Your question might be better helped on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ , given its rather broad scope and little R-specifity. That said, why not just predict mushroom occurence on the finer resolution (World Clim Data) and mask the result with the forest layer regardless of its coarser resolution?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this, I can use the same resolution landcover for the model, it will be able to decipher trees and grass. Ok thanks again, hopefully this works

Comment: resample will go much faster if you use the "terra" package instead of "raster"

Comment: @RobertHijmans I have been using terra and it eventually crashed. It may be due to my computing power which could be better. However, I'm currently creating a new project and starting again and potentially try it if I get this one running.

Comment: In cases like this, I would first try things for a small area and/or a low spatial resolution.

Comment: @RobertHijmans, I agree I think I just jumped ahead a bit. I have it working now thanks to all your tutorials and just using the data available from geodata now that has all the same resolutions. Thanks for you help